# Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) for Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, encryption, azure-sql-database, tde

Can we use TDE feature with Azure SQL Database in production application? Or only SQL Sever Enterprise edition declares TDE feature as released?

Comment: Yes we can use the mandatory thing we need enterprise edition either Azure OR linked server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dn948096.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE TDE is now GA see [Blog Post here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsecurity/archive/2015/10/14/azure-sql-database-transparent-data-encryption-general-availability.aspx)**

You can use TDE on any Azure SQL Database. You can follow [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn948096.aspx) to enable TDE on an Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Good news) Thank you alot.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: As of May 2, 2017, ASD's are encrypted via TDE by default.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/newly-created-azure-sql-databases-encrypted-by-default/